# MUI date picker wont show dates before 1900

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, momentjs

i want a datepicker that allows the user to set dates from 1850s, but in the mui datepicker starts from 1900s.

ive recreated the issue in [this codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/hopeful-morning-gkvy7r?file=/demo.tsx:0-1176)

im using mui in the rest of the project, so i really dont wanna switch to another package, also i've tried replacing momentjs with datefns and dayjs to no avail

Comment: This is an issue with the library. The dates are limited to between 1900 and 2099. https://github.com/mui/mui-x/issues/7072

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as evolutionxbox pointed out mui The dates are limited to between 1900 and 2099, however adding minDate={moment(minDate)} prop to  along with corresponding shouldDisableYear seems to have to have fixed the issue.